# Can I load an entire db with tables inside, using Navigation Properties?

Tags: mysql, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a MySQL db with tables that all relate to each other in a straight line.

**Handover -> Sections -> Entries -> Replies**

I'd like to do a single http request for a JSON array of these tables.

Using the following in my Controller currently:

```
    public JsonResult GetHandovers()
    {
        using (tidrapportEntities context = new tidrapportEntities())
        {
            context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

            var result2 = context.handovers
                .Include(x => x.handoversections
                .Select(z => z.handoverentries
                .Select(y => y.handoverreplies)))
                //.Where(p => p.Country == "Sweden")
                .Select(w => new
                {
                    Country = w.Country,
                    Id = w.HandOverId,
                    Sections = w.handoversections
                }).ToList();

            return Json(result2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

But in the end, this does not return the data of all the layers.

```
[
    {
        "Country": "Sweden",
        "Id": 1,
        "Sections": [
            {
                "handoverentries": [],
                "handovers": null,
                "SectionId": 3,
                "HandOverId": 1,
                "Title": "Misc"
            },
            {
                "handoverentries": [],
                "handovers": null,
                "SectionId": 2,
                "HandOverId": 1,
                "Title": "OOH"
            },
            {
                "handoverentries": [],
                "handovers": null,
                "SectionId": 1,
                "HandOverId": 1,
                "Title": "DOH"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I load all 4 tables and get them in one single JSON? I will accept any method, as long as I can get it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gathering from this code that you would like to get `Handovers`, `HandoverSections`, `HandoverEntries` and `HandoverReplies`

```
.Include(x => x.handoversections
            .Select(z => z.handoverentries
            .Select(y => y.handoverreplies)))
```

When using `Include` you can provide an expression, as you are above: `Include(x => x.handoversections)` but one of the overloads is a string. You can use it like this: `.Include("School.Classes.Pupils")`. In your case I think it would like this:

```
context.handovers
    .Include("handoversections.handoverentries")
    .Include("handoversections.handovers")
```

Remember that you can chain `Include` for all of the navigation properties you want.

Comment: Thank you for this! Will try it tomorrow. Can I only use the string overload to achieve this? I was slightly avoiding it to be honest.

Comment: @WilliamS I believe so if it's a one to many relationship. If it's a one to one relationship you may be able to use the expression instead. I'm not 100% sure. You can try both.

Comment: Hi. You have solved my issue, but it appears that based on the amount of circular references I'm getting when trying to serialize it to JSON, I need to implement DTO's (and probably a Repository for good measure). I will mark your answer as accepted.